Python .exe doesn't run on another machine
I try to create a python .exe to allow anyone on my company to run it.
However, my project uses jpype to include java classes, you can see below my file callback.py :
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash_app import app
import jpype
import jpype.imports
from jpype.types import *
import math

# Launch JVM
jpype.startJVM('-ea', classpath=["project.jar"])
Constants = JClass("com.mypackage.Constants")


@app.callback(
    Output('output-div', 'children'),
    [Input('input-box', 'value')]
)
def update_output(value):
    print(Constants.SMALLEST_DISTANCE)
    return f'Vous avez entré : {value}'

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function() {
        return navigator.permissions.query({name:'notifications'})
    }
    """,
    Output("notification-permission", "data"),
    Input("notify-btn", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(result) {
        if (result.state == 'granted') {
            new Notification("Dash notification", { body: "Notification already granted!"});
            return null;
        } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Notification.requestPermission().then(res => {
                    if (res == 'granted') {
                        new Notification("Dash notification", { body: "Notification granted!"});
                        resolve();
                    } else {
                        reject(`Permission not granted: ${res}`)
                    }
                })
            });
        } else {
            return result.state;
        }
    }
    """,
    Output("notification-output", "children"),
    Input("notification-permission", "data"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)

my dash_app.py:
from dash import *
import dash_html_components as html

app = Dash(__name__)
from callback import *

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Exemple de Dash App'),
    html.Div('Entrez du texte :'),
    dcc.Input(id='input-box', type='text', value=''),
    html.Div(id='output-div'),dcc.Store(id="notification-permission"),
        html.Button("Notify", id="notify-btn"),
        html.Div(id="notification-output")
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', port=8050, debug=False, use_reloader=False)


and this is my dash_app.spec:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['dash_app.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[('project.jar', '.')],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='dash_app',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)


to create my .exe i use : pyinstaller dash_app.spec
the .exe works on my machine but on another machine i have this :
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "callback.py", line 10, in <module>
    Constants = JClass("com.mypackage.Constants")
  File "jpype\_jclass.py", line 99, in __new__
TypeError: Class com.mypackage.Constants is not found
[21812] Failed to execute script 'dash_app' due to unhandled exception!


first you can add os.listdir() to check what files are in folder when you run code. PyInstaller creates self-extracting .zip file which put code in some folder and it may need to use "/some/folder/project.jar"  and documentation for PyInstaller should have information how to use full path to extra files in your code
